# To Rename the Inbuild error message

Tags: image

I want to Rename the by default error message when anyone hit the button without selecting the color.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried amending the error messages using the transalation.csv file?

In your theme folder create a `locale/[locale_code]/translate.csv` file.

Example: `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

And add this line:

> "your custom error message"

And finally refresh Translations cache.

**OR**

For a yellow "warning" message (the one you probably want for this purpose), use

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Please log in to track
>   your order');

For a green "success" message, use

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Tracking successful');

For a red "error" message, use

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('There was an error
>   tracking your parcel')

**OR**

put this code in your controller

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if (!$session->getCustomerId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('You are not logged in');
}
```

Comment: What if changes all error message ?

Comment: i have updated my answer..please try this out.

Comment: So that will rename only the error message I want to rename it isn't it ?

Comment: i want to just confirming after made the changes as you suggest it will be change the error message for configurable products or swatches or it will change the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses prototype validation in forms. All validation rules are defined inside the file `lib/prototype/validation.js`. For example, you can find the message definition in the provided screenshot here :

File : `lib\prototype\validation.js`

```
Validation.addAllThese([
    ...
    ['required-entry', 'This is a required field.', function(v) {
                return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
    ...
]);
```

Changing this message will eventually solve your issue. But since it is a kind of core edit, better you define your own validation rules. For more information, you can refer [**Inchoo Post**](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/magento-form-field-ajax-validation/).

Let me know if you have further doubts.

Comment: I want to change error message for a configurable swatch error message only in this case how can i manage to do it